# HTML tags are not working when embedded in PHP

Tags: php, html, while-loop

my HTML tags are working well but when embedded PHP code inside it the tags after PHP code not showing

The PHP code is fetched some data from MySQL database in order to show in the select tag as options.

```
<div class="linetxt"><!--Trainer Name-->
    <label for="trainee_name">Trainer Name</label>
    <span class="input">
        <select name="trainerName" id="">
            <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT trainer_name ,trainer_id FROM trainer"))){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['trainer_id'].'">'.$row['trainer_name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure you have a `.php` file extension otherwise it will not work

Comment: Yes, the extension is `.php` there is another code PHP in the page and it works well

Comment: so you get some error or a blank page?

Comment: And what happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Also, there seems to be no element with `id="trainee_name"` regarding your label's `for` attribute

Comment: yes, the query is work. I solved  the problem according to **LucasLaurens**  the problem because I mix the query with while statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues with the code (A), your question is not well presented (B) and you don't appear to have made any effort towards investigating the issue yourself (C).

A spans multiple things - in addition to B & C you might want to visit codereview.stackexchange for pointers on how to write reliable code.

Regarding B: The snippet of code here omits critical PHP instructions required to make it work - the recommendations are to include a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code listing to illustrate your problem.

C: While you have attempted to capture the errors PHP is emitting by changing the config in your code - and if you are getting some html output that suggests the PHP code parses OK but is encountering an error later. You didn't mention if the html content *after* your PHP code shows in the output (maybe your query is not finding any data).

You should verify that your error logging is working as expected (by testing it) and whether your code is writing any errors to the log.

When integrating with a service outside of PHP (like a DBMS) then things can happen there which are not PHP errors. Extensions for such integrations will have interfaces which report status in the return codes (you are not checking the value returned by the mysqli functions) and an interface to [retrieve any specific error messages](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp) which you should be polling in your code.

You are running a new query each time the loop iterates - so the reason you are not seeing any output is that the code is still running (and will continue until the instance runs out of memory or time).

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to put your query before your `while` 
And you have to fetch all information inside the `while`.

I don't know how you made your database but if you want to get each data row, here's a better way:

**An example:**
(call your database)

```
$req = $bdd->("SELECT * FROM table");
while($r = $req->fetch()){
   echo $r["name"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. my code is work after separate the query from the while statement

Comment: with pleasure ;)

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
$sql= "SELECT trainer_name ,trainer_id FROM trainer";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$xxxx = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 foreach ($xxxx as $row) 
{ 
    var_dump($row);
}
```